# How To Reload xserver After a Change in Keyboard Layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout, x-server

I do a change in my current keyboard layout *English(US-Dvorak)* but it does not react with the following code without changing back-and-forth to another keyboard layout, for xserver reloading

```
# restore your current keyboard settings; 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xkb-data
# you close also extra Control at Capslock etc
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"

# do any change in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`; etc add about 3rd level config for some [A,a] like [A,a,x]. 

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data

# TODO Is there any command which can cause reload of xserver regardless you have active your current keyboard where you do the change?
```

I do not want to manually cause the reloading of xserver by doing such a switch. It would be great to do by a one-liner.

Systems: Ubuntu 16.04
Linux kernel: 4.6
Keyboard model: pc105
Keyboard layout: English (Dvorak) = US-dvorak
Related thread: [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/648659/25388) about *How to Get A with Dots in Dvorak of Ubuntu 16.04?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard):

> To apply new [keyboard] settings, restarting the keyboard-setup service should suffice, otherwise you can try to restart kernel input system via udev:
>
> ```
> udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
> ```

For completeness, restarting `keyboard-setup` would look like

```
# For Ubuntu < 16.04
service keyboard-setup restart
# For Ubuntu >= 16.04
systemctl restart keyboard-setup
```

Comment: perfect! Had to use `sudo udevadm ...` though.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find here anything stable solution but to restart the system. 
Xserver gets confused very fast, which I could resolve only by restarting the system.